# In what language is the following code written?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Can anyone explain what language is used here?

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/message/{userId}/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const userId = event.params.userId;
});
```

Comment: That is JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

It's JavaScript running in [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which is a managed node.js environment.